# Riverpod 2 - filter using AsyncNotifierProvider .select

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

Assuming I have an `AsyncNotifierProvider` from Riverpod 2

```
final asyncOnlineUsersProvider =
    AsyncNotifierProvider.autoDispose<AsyncUserListNotifier, List<User>>(() {
  return AsyncUserListNotifier();
});
```

I want to render a widget that only shows the number of users, and I want to optimize it so only if the number changes to render again. For that I choose `.select` like this:

```
final listSize = ref.watch(
  asyncOnlineUsersProvider.select((data) => AsyncValue.data(data.value?.length)),
);
```

then we render the widget

```
listSize.when(
  data: (data) => Text('Size:$data'),
  error: (err, stack) => const Text('error'),
  loading: () => const Text('loading'),
);
```

The problem with this approach is that loading is not called, instead it will show `Size:null` while data is fetched, then it will show the actual size: `Size:12`

Is there a way to implement this so I can use `.select` to render the widgets only when the size of the list changes, but also show loading while fetching the data?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this way will work for you:

```dart
// ListWidget
asyncOnlineUsersProvider.when(
  data: (_) => const DataWidget(),
  error: (err, stack) => const Text('error'),
  loading: () => const Text('loading'),
);
```

and

```dart
// DataWidget
final listSize = ref.watch(
  asyncOnlineUsersProvider.select((data) => AsyncData(data.value?.length)),
);

listSize.maybeWhen(
  data: (data) => data.isEmpty ? Text('List empty') : Text('Size:$data'),
  orElse: () => const SizedBox.shrink(),
);
```

The `orElse` block will never be shown.

Comment: So.. I'm showing the loading text when I try to render the list, on number of users I only render the widget once the number is not null, else it renders SizedBox.shrink(). What if I only want to render the users number ? Could using a different provider for users size be the solution?

Comment: @DouaBeri And what will be shown at the moment when the data is loaded, but the list is empty? It is this "empty list" widget that can be shown in the `data: (data) =>` block by adding an additional check for null inside

Comment: if the list is empty it will show Size:0 , but he needs to fetch the data from back-end first, and I want to be able to show a loading while the data is fetched

Comment: if your `asyncOnlineUsersProvider` has loading states, then `Text('loading')` will be shown. If the data has been loaded, then depending on if the list is empty, show `Text('Empty list')`, else `Text('Size:$data')`. When `asyncOnlineUsersProvider` is updated, you will see the update. `DataWidget` you will see only when there is data in one form or another